# How to put most recent posts on top with backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

This is how my collection view looks like, how am i going to arrange my models in the collection so that the recently added model is rendered at the top?

```
PostsApp.Views.Posts = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);

    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },

    addOne: function(post){
        var postView = new PostsApp.Views.Post({model:post, collection :this.collection});
        postView.render();
        this.$el.append(postView.el);
    }
});
```

edit: Prepend method seems to be working but I also tried the comparator like this, it doesnt seem to be working, whats my problem?

```
PostsApp.Models.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/tweet',
    idAttribute: '_id',
    defaults:{
        name: '',
        adress: '',
        pictureUrl: '',
        postListing: '',
        comments: '',
        date_created: new Date()
    }
    }
});

PostsApp.Collections.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PostsApp.Models.Post,
    url: '/tweet',
    comparator: function(post){
        return post.get("date_created");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `prepend` method instead of `append`
2. Use [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) to store
   your models in the order you want.

BTW adding elements to the DOM in the loop is a bad idea.

---

```
var collection = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url : 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=vpetrychuk&count=9',
    comparator: function(post) {
        // comparator is not necessary because tweets are already sorted
        return +new Date(post.get('created_at'));
    }
}));

var view = new (Backbone.View.extend({
    el : document.body,
    collection : collection,
    initialize : function () {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'sync', this.render);
    },
    render : function () {
        var html = []; // or http://davidwalsh.name/documentfragment
        this.collection.each(function (model) {
            html.unshift('<div>' + model.get('created_at') + '</div>');
        });
        this.$el.prepend(html.join(''));
    }
}));

collection.fetch({dataType:'jsonp'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/jgztL/

---

I would recommend to read this awesome post - [Rendering Backbone Collections with DocumentFragment](http://elving.me/post/48040344160/rendering-backbone-collections-with-documentfragment)

Comment: thanks.. I edited my question about the comparator, if adding elements to the DOM in the loop is a bad idea where else should I be doing it? I watched the codeschool backbone classes and thats how they did it..

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven I have edited the answer once again by adding a useful link ;)